# Java RMI NoClassDefFoundError for javax.json.JsonValue in Remote object

Tags: java, rmi

Running into Exception caused during call to `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().`

*javax.json.jar* is on the classpath and is used in many other places in the application without any problems.

This part of the application worked fine until I added a method that returned a JsonValue to the remote object.

Any ideas?

```
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/json/JsonValue
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:416)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:275)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:252)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:378)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
```

NOTE:
I also tried running the rmiregistry with codebase pointed directly at the javax.json.jar but the exception remains

```
rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///JarLibrary/javax.json.jar &
```

Comment: Could you  show us the signature of the method that you added to your remote interface ?

Comment: @QuakeCore: public static JsonValue getJsonValue()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Running into Exception caused during call to `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().`

No you aren't. See the stack trace. It's happening in `Registry.bind().`

You need to run the *server* with the `java.rmi.server.codebase` property set, but a file:// codebase URL isn't going to work unless either all the clients are running in the server host, in which case you don't really need the codebase feature at all, or it points to a shared folder in a form that both the Registry and the clients can use. It's usually HTTP.

But I question whether you need the codebase feature at all. You just have to ensure that the relevant jar file is on the CLASSPATH of both the Registry and the clients. The simplest way to ensure that for the Registry is to use `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` in the server JVM instead of the external `rmiregistry` program.

I'm also wondering why you're using JSON at all. RMI is built over Object Serialization. You don't need to add another serializer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Registry.bind() is being called as a result of my code calling UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(). My registry and server are running on the same machine, clients are distributed across a network. Are you saying I don't need to run rmiregistry externally if I call LocateRegistry.createRegistry() before calling UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()?  I'll give it a try.  Also, I'm using JSON to communicate with a network of Node.js servers.

Comment: `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()` (a) does not call `Registry.bind(),` and (b) does not appear in the stack trace. *Ergo* 'during `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`' is not correct.

Comment: I pruned the stack trace at the line referencing my function call, which was a line in my code calling UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(), fyi :)

Comment: No. It came from your line of code that calls `Registry.bind()`. See the stack trace.

Comment: The next line of the stack trace (which I did not show) was:  **at mai.mabs.Mabs.<init>(Mabs.java:390)** where line 390 in Mabs.java is **rmi_stub  = (MabsRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(r, rmi_port);** hence my attributing the source of the exception to UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject().  In any case, I thank you sincerely for helping.